# Using DISTINCT on the second select variable

Tags: sqlite

I have the following code that works:

```
   select distinct count(b), a from test group by a order by count(b) DESC limit 10;
```

But I'd like the output to actually display a, count(b) instead (switching the order).  Unfortunately

```
   select a, distinct count(b) from test group by a order by count(b) DESC limit 10;
```

does not work.  Small question I know, it's just a pain to have to keep changing the order in another program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you have to understand that 
 `select distinct count(b), a` means DISTINCT of `count(b), a` and not just count(b)

That is why the second one doesn't work, you can't have distinct on a subset of columns.

To understand it more : DISTINCT gives one row when all the values of the rows are the same,
if you want to do it on just `count(b)`, and 2 rows have the same value for `count(b)`, which value of `a` should be shown ??

This is why it is impossible to have distinct on a subset of columns

To get one value for each `count(b)` and any value of `a` 
I'm not sure but you can try this :

`select max(a) from (select distinct count(b) from test group by a order by count(b) DESC ) GROUP BY count(b)`

Comment: Ahh I see.  In this case, it doesn't matter to me which value of a is shown, as if two rows have equal count(b)'s, then the a's will be very similar (this dataset is a combination of two similar datasets).

Comment: in this case you can simply do `select distinct a,count(b) from test group by a order by count(b) DESC limit 10;`

Comment: That doesn't work, as it displays both a's (the a values are similar, not equal, if the counts are the same).  I want to just output one of the two rows, doesn't matter which.

Comment: I edited my answer, not sure about it, and maybe not the optimal way, but you can try it